# Unable to find Elements on native Android App - Appium, WebdriverIO, Mocha and Chai

Tags: android, mocha.js, appium

I am unable to find elements on native `Android` app (`Appium`, `WebdriverIO`, `Mocha` and `Chai`).

Not sure why its unable to find elements and apply `click()` event on that specific element so that it automatically takes to the next screen of the app. And not sure, what this actually means:

```
{"status":7,"value":"No element found"}
```

I tried doing this as well:

```
client.elementByXPath('xpath val')
```

but this last line throws:

```
elementByXPath not a function
```

My code:

```
describe('Testing', function(){
    before(function(){
        this.timeout(50000);
        return client.init();
    });
    describe('Test CALCU addition', function(){
        it('should display list of projects', function(){
            client.click(
                'android=new UiSelector().resourceId(
                    "uk.co.polestar.app:id/firstLineDisplayName")');
        });
    });
});
```

Error logs below:

```
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session 200 41752 ms - 1203
[HTTP] 
[HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session/975b8acc-151e-482c-9a66-60446e1023e0/element
[HTTP] {"using":"-android uiautomator","value":"new UiSelector().resourceId(\"uk.co.polestar.app:id/firstLineDisplayName\")"}
[debug] [MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.findElement() with args: ["-android uiautomator","new UiSelector().resourceId(\"uk.co.polestar.app:id/firstLineDisplayName\")","975b8acc-151e-482c-9a66-60446e1023e0"]
[debug] [BaseDriver] Valid locator strategies for this request: xpath, id, class name, accessibility id, -android uiautomator
[debug] [BaseDriver] Waiting up to 0 ms for condition
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] Sending command to android: {"cmd":"action","action":"find","params":{"strategy":"-android uiautomator","selector":"new UiSelector().resourceId(\"uk.co.polestar.app:id/firstLineDisplayName\")","context":"","multiple":false}}
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session/975b8acc-151e-482c-9a66-60446e1023e0/element - - ms - -
[HTTP] 
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"find","params":{"strategy":"-android uiautomator","selector":"new UiSelector().resourceId(\"uk.co.polestar.app:id/firstLineDisplayName\")","context":"","multiple":false}}
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command action: find
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Finding 'new UiSelector().resourceId("uk.co.polestar.app:id/firstLineDisplayName")' using 'ANDROID_UIAUTOMATOR' with the contextId: '' multiple: false
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Parsing selector: new UiSelector().resourceId("uk.co.polestar.app:id/firstLineDisplayName")
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] UiSelector coerce type: class java.lang.String arg: "uk.co.polestar.app:id/firstLineDisplayName"
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Using: UiSelector[RESOURCE_ID=uk.co.polestar.app:id/firstLineDisplayName]
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Failed to locate element. Clearing Accessibility cache and retrying.
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Finding 'new UiSelector().resourceId("uk.co.polestar.app:id/firstLineDisplayName")' using 'ANDROID_UIAUTOMATOR' with the contextId: '' multiple: false
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] Received command result from bootstrap
[debug] [MJSONWP] Matched JSONWP error code 7 to NoSuchElementError
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Parsing selector: new UiSelector().resourceId("uk.co.polestar.app:id/firstLineDisplayName")
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] UiSelector coerce type: class java.lang.String arg: "uk.co.polestar.app:id/firstLineDisplayName"
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Using: UiSelector[RESOURCE_ID=uk.co.polestar.app:id/firstLineDisplayName]
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Returning result: {"status":7,"value":"No element found"}
```

But the result is PASS:

```
automatedtesting@automatedtesting:~/CALCU$ mocha webdriverio-calcu.js
```

․

1 passing (43s)